# How to screenshot an active non-focused window using WinRT

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime, .net-6.0, screenshot

I'm looking for a way to screenshot an active (non-focused) window using its `IntPtr`, without using `user32.dll` `PrintWindow` as it requires running the app as admin.

I was able to screen capture using WinRT following this repo with some adjustments to make it work in dotnet 6 -
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/dotnet/WPF/ScreenCapture

Now all that's left is to convert the frame (`Direct3D11CaptureFrame`) to an image that I can actually save.
For that purpose, I found this tutorial -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture

It's for UWP, but the idea is to Convert the D3D11 surface into a Win2D object by doing -

```
// Convert our D3D11 surface into a Win2D object.
CanvasBitmap canvasBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(
    _canvasDevice,
    frame.Surface);
```

The issue is that `_canvasDevice` in that sample is an `ICanvasResourceCreator` which I don't have by following the WPF screen capture repo shared above.
Iv'e tried creating a device using -

```
CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice()
```

But using that device in the `CreateFromDirect3D11Surface` method throws an exception -
`The requested operation is not supported. (0x88990003)`

If anyone has an idea how to fix that issue or achieve my goal using a different approach I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Edit -
Added below the entire `OnFrameArrived` method, where I try to convert the frame to `CanvasBitmap` like its done in the UWP code sample I linked above -

````cs
        private void OnFrameArrived(Direct3D11CaptureFramePool sender, object args)
        {
            var newSize = false;

            using (var frame = sender.TryGetNextFrame())
            {
                var canvasDevice = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();

                //Convert our D3D11 surface into a Win2D object.
                //this method below throws the exception
                _currentFrame = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(
                    canvasDevice,
                    frame.Surface);
                
                if (frame.ContentSize.Width != lastSize.Width ||
                    frame.ContentSize.Height != lastSize.Height)
                {
                    // The thing we have been capturing has changed size.
                    // We need to resize the swap chain first, then blit the pixels.
                    // After we do that, retire the frame and then recreate the frame pool.
                    newSize = true;
                    lastSize = frame.ContentSize;
                    swapChain.ResizeBuffers(
                        2, 
                        lastSize.Width, 
                        lastSize.Height,
                        Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm, 
                        SwapChainFlags.None);
                }

                using (var backBuffer = swapChain.GetBackBuffer<Texture2D>(0))
                using (var bitmap = Direct3D11Helper.CreateSharpDXTexture2D(frame.Surface))
                {
                    d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(bitmap, backBuffer);
                }

            } // Retire the frame.

            swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);

            if (newSize)
            {
                framePool.Recreate(
                    device,
                    DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,
                    2,
                    lastSize);
            }
        }
    ```
````

Comment: Do you have a full reproducing sample as UWP? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier, the error I experience is in WPF.
The link I shared has a working sample in UWP.
I'm trying to mimic that behavior in my WPF version of that.

Comment: Iv'e edited my question and added the full method code at where the exception is thrown.
A full reproduced repo is available in the WPF screen capture sample link I shared.

Comment: Why do you want to use Win2D (Direct2D wrapper) to save a bitmap file, if that's what you're trying to do (it's still unclear)? You can use WinRT's classes in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging

Comment: Could you please explain it further?
"Why do you want to use Win2D" - cuz looking into the Microsoft code samples I shared above, this is the way to take screenshots using WinRT.
I need to somehow convert `Direct3D11CaptureFrame` into an image I can save on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Direct2D (Win2D is a wrapper over Direct2D) to get the bytes from a surface. You can get the bytes using standard DirectX API, then write them to a file using the Bitmap API you want.

Here is an example using WinRT's [SoftwareBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap) and [BitmapEncoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder), but you can use GDI+ (System.Drawing.Bitmap, WIC, etc.) to save a file.

Starting from the BasicCapture.cs file, modify it like this:

```
public class BasicCapture : IDisposable
{
    ...
    private Texture2D cpuTexture; // add this
    private bool saved = false; // add this

    public BasicCapture(IDirect3DDevice d, GraphicsCaptureItem i)
    {
        ...
        cpuTexture = CreateTexture2D(item.Size.Width, item.Size.Height); // add this
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        session?.Dispose();
        framePool?.Dispose();
        swapChain?.Dispose();
        d3dDevice?.Dispose();
        cpuTexture?.Dispose(); // add this
    }

    private Texture2D CreateTexture2D(int width, int height)
    {
        // create add texture2D 2D accessible by the CPU
        var desc = new Texture2DDescription()
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging,
            Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
            ArraySize = 1,
            MipLevels = 1,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
        };
        return new Texture2D(d3dDevice, desc);
    }

    private void OnFrameArrived(Direct3D11CaptureFramePool sender, object args)
    {
        using (var frame = sender.TryGetNextFrame())
        {
            ...

            using (var backBuffer = swapChain.GetBackBuffer<SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D>(0))
            using (var bitmap = Direct3D11Helper.CreateSharpDXTexture2D(frame.Surface))
            {
                d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(bitmap, backBuffer);
                
                // add this to copy the DirectX resource into the CPU-readable texture2D
                d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(bitmap, cpuTexture);

                // now,  this is just an example that only saves the first frame
                // but you could also use
                // d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(cpuTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags.None, out var stream); and d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.UnMapSubresource
                // to get the bytes (out from the returned stream)
                if (!_saved)
                {
                    _saved = true;
                    Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        // get IDirect3DSurface from texture (from WPF sample's helper code)
                        var surf = Direct3D11Helper.CreateDirect3DSurfaceFromSharpDXTexture(cpuTexture);
                        
                        // build a WinRT's SoftwareBitmap from this surface/texture
                        var softwareBitmap = await SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromSurfaceAsync(surf);
                        using (var file = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                        {
                            // create a PNG encoder
                            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, file.AsRandomAccessStream());
                            
                            // set the bitmap to it & flush
                            encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
                            await encoder.FlushAsync();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty for that elaborated answer and an easy-to-follow code.
Works great, cheers Simon

Comment: Simon, do you happen to know why the logic above wouldn't work when running on a background thread?
If I try to start the capture using Task.Run() a new frame is never arrived.
Running it on the main thread causes issues with UI blocking.

Comment: @ben - Depends on details but have you initialized your thread as STA (vs MTA which is the default state), otherwise ask another question with reproducible code.

Comment: I read about STA vs MTA, I do think that's part of the issue but not completely sure how to uttlize it for my use-case.
Created a new question with reproducible code including some of what we spoke of here to add the screenshot capability.
If you get the chance to look at it - 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/75940867/7210967

Thx!