# How to take a screenshot from a background thread using WinRT?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sta, winrt-component

I'm having issues with WinRT ScreenCapture blocking/freezing my UI.

My app is looping through selected windows and takes a screenshot of each every few seconds.
Every time a screenshot is taken the UI animation is lagging and sometimes the UI just freezes completely until I focus on another app which somehow releases the UI block.

Using this ScreenCapture repo as a reference -
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/dotnet/WPF/ScreenCapture

In order to add screenshot capability, I've adjusted the `BasicCapture.cs` accordingly -

```cs
public class BasicCapture : IDisposable
{
    ...
    private Texture2D cpuTexture; // added this
    private bool screenshotReady; // added this

    public BasicCapture(IDirect3DDevice d, GraphicsCaptureItem i)
    {
        ...
        cpuTexture = CreateTexture2D(item.Size.Width, item.Size.Height); // added this
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        session?.Dispose();
        framePool?.Dispose();
        swapChain?.Dispose();
        d3dDevice?.Dispose();
        cpuTexture?.Dispose(); // added this
    }

    private Texture2D CreateTexture2D(int width, int height)
    {
        // create add texture2D 2D accessible by the CPU
        var desc = new Texture2DDescription()
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Read,
            Usage = ResourceUsage.Staging,
            Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
            ArraySize = 1,
            MipLevels = 1,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
        };
        return new Texture2D(d3dDevice, desc);
    }

    private void OnFrameArrived(Direct3D11CaptureFramePool sender, object args)
    {
        using (var frame = sender.TryGetNextFrame())
        {
            ...

            using (var backBuffer = swapChain.GetBackBuffer<SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D>(0))
            using (var bitmap = Direct3D11Helper.CreateSharpDXTexture2D(frame.Surface))
            {
                d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(bitmap, backBuffer);
                
                if (screenshotReady == false)
                {
                    // added this to copy the DirectX resource into the CPU-readable texture2D
                    d3dDevice.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(bitmap, cpuTexture);
                    screenshotReady = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

        public async Task<Image> ScreenshotWindow()
        {
            screenshotReady = false;

            StartCapture();

            //await for screenshot to be captured
            while (screenshotReady == false) await Task.Delay(50);

            // get IDirect3DSurface from texture
            using var surf = Direct3D11Helper.CreateDirect3DSurfaceFromSharpDXTexture(cpuTexture);

            // build a WinRT's SoftwareBitmap from this surface/texture
            using var softwareBitmap = await SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromSurfaceAsync(surf);

            using var InMemoryStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();            
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, InMemoryStream);

            encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
            using var stream = InMemoryStream.AsStream();
            return Image.Load(stream);            
        }
}
```

And to the `BasicSampleApplication.cs` Iv'e added this -

```cs
        public async Task<Image> ScreenshotWindow(GraphicsCaptureItem item)
        {
            capture = new BasicCapture(device, item);

            var surface = capture.CreateSurface(compositor);
            brush.Surface = surface;

            var img = await capture.ScreenshotWindow();

            StopCapture();

            return img;
        }
```

As I don't actually need to visually show the captured screen on my app, I instantiate the
`BasicSampleApplication` without any visual properties, and I do it once on the app startup -

```cs
            // Create the compositor.
            compositor = new Compositor();
            _screenshotService = new BasicSampleApplication(compositor);
```

Now all that's left is to iterate through the selectedWindows and screenshot them -

```cs
        private async Task ScreenshotSelectedWindows()
        {
            while (ScreenshotsEnabled)
            {
                foreach (var wnd in _selectedWindows)
                {
                    GraphicsCaptureItem item = CaptureHelper.CreateItemForWindow(wnd.WindowHandler);
                    using var img = await _screenshotService.ScreenshotWindow(item);
                }
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            }
        }
```

And now when I use `ScreenshotSelectedWindows()` it works, but as I initially said its making the UI animations lag, and sometimes the UI just freezes completely till I remove focus.

Iv'e tried calling this method from a background task -

```cs
Task.Run(()=>ScreenshotSelectedWindows());
```

For some reason doing that won't work, the `OnFrameArrived` callback is never triggered.
Iv'e also tried to instantiate the `BasicSampleApplication` on the background thread but creating the compositor on a background thread throws an error `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. '`.

Any tips on how can I achieve that screenshot goal without blocking/freezing my UI?

Thanks!

Edit -
I'll add a link to a GitHub issue as it seems to be referencing my issue specifically, which I fail to translate to my code :D

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/issues/69#issuecomment-1498188216

Comment: Difficult to say fom pieces of code like that, every details is important with this type of code. Do you have a simple full reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Got it, will start working on reproducible code, might take a while as using this API on dotnet 6 requires multiple patches ...
btw, following you last recommendation I looked into running that on a STA thread.
It seems like I can't create the compositor outside the main app thread, it throws `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied.'`.
and if I try to use the compositor from another thread the `OnFrameArrived`  is never triggered. 
Any idea how to create a compositor on another thread?

Comment: I was able to create a compositor from a background thread following this solution - 
https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/issues/617#issuecomment-740757111

But still, `OnFrameArrived` never triggers

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Creating a compositor on a background thread requires creating a dispatcher queue -
https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/issues/617#issuecomment-740757111

It's not actually necessary for my use case, `OnFrameArrived` wasn't triggered on a background thread because the frame pool needs to be created using -
`Direct3D11CaptureFramePool.CreateFreeThreaded`

Everything is explained with better code samples than I shared in this Github Issue comment -

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/issues/69#issuecomment-1498245106